# How do i connect my route to controller in sage 10?

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress

I am trying to create a controller that handles form submission trough a AJAX call.

I tried to follow larvel's document, sage document nothing is working. I am getting ../signup 404 (Not Found)

controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class NewsLetterSignupController extends Controller
{
    public function SignupToNewsletter(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'firstName' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'lastName' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Form submitted successfully']);
    }
}
```

route

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\NewsLetterSignupController;

Route::post('/signup', 'App\Http\Controllers\NewsLetterSignupController@SignupToNewsletter');
```

Comment: Still getting 404 error

Answer (score 1):

First, add the route name in `routes/ajax.php`:

```php
Route::post('signup', [App\Http\Controllers\Ajax\NewsLetterSignupController::class, 'signupToNewsletter'])->name('news-letter-signup');
```

Then, in your Sage 10 application, you can use the `route` method to generate the URL for the specified route:

```php
route('ajax.news-letter-signup');
```

This will generate the URL for the `news-letter-signup` route, including any parameters if required. You can use this generated URL in your POST request.

If you don't have an `ajax.php` route group, you can create one similar to `web.php`. You can refer to the Laravel documentation for more information on route groups. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-groups)

Comment: now i am getting 'Class "App\Http\Controllers\Controller" not found '

Comment: Please correct your namespace in your controller.
After change in namespace in controller please dump-autoload your composer:
```Composer dump-autoload```